# How to check a variable's value using a debugger in XCode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, variables

How do you use the debugger in XCode to see if a variable is nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pointer's address is 0x000000 it's nil.

Hovering over the variable in the debugger should show a tooltip, this will show you the type of the variable, the name and a value. If it is a pointer to an object the value will be the address that it points to. This will be `0x0` if it is nil.

Answer (score 2):

Just open up the GDB Console and type `po myvar` or insert a breakpoint after you set your variable and move your cursor over the target variable.

Comment: It doesn't say anything. If I type something in gdb it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you stopped at a breakpoint whilst running the app? It's probably easier to just type `p myvar`, the output would look like this if myvar is an NSMutableArray and set to nil, `$1 = (NSMutableArray *) 0x0`.

Comment: As Greg mentioned you have to stop at a breakpoint to use both methods

Comment: Yeah, I'm at a breakpoint. The other method doesn't work either.